# Carrier Ethernet, difference between ESP and EVC

Tags: ethernet, metro-ethernet

Does anyone know the difference between an ESP (Ethernet switching path) and an EVC (Ethernet virtual connection)?

Best regards,
Michelot

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

An EVC is a service providing ethernet connectivity between two or
more user-network interfaces across a metro ethernet network.  It can
be point-to-point, point-to-multipoint (tree topology), or
multipoint-to-multipoint (LAN topology).  It provides security,
ensuring that traffic on the EVC doesn't get mixed up with that on
other connections in the network; and it may optionally provide guaranteed quality of service.
See [MEF 12.2](http://www.metroethernetforum.org/Assets/Technical_Specifications/PDF/MEF_12.2.pdf).

An ESP is a *unidirectional* connection within a provider backbone
bridge network.  ESPs can be used to route traffic in an EVC, if
the provider's network supports it, but there are also other routing
technologies that can be used instead.  The user is not typically aware of
the particular method used.  See [IEEE 802.1Qay-2009](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.1Qay-2009.pdf) for the formal
ESP definition.